# How to call a post method in REST API service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, rest

I am studying rest API service. I have a database table that I want to add the item to using a rest API. I have an `WebInvoke` method to do `PUT` but how do I call a post method in REST API service? i.e I to want call `createperson` method(by passing parameters).

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class RestSerivce : IRestSerivce
{
  List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
  int personCount = 0;

  public Person CreatePerson(Person createPerson)
  {           
      createPerson.ID = (++personCount).ToString();
      persons.Add(createPerson);
      InsertDetails(createPerson);
      return createPerson;
  }

  public bool InsertDetails(Person createPerson)
  {
       string connectionString = "Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd;Initial Catalog=Demodb;Server=REFL-19";

       using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
       {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PersonDetails (id,Name,Age) VALUES (" + createPerson.ID + ","+createPerson.Name+","+createPerson.Age+");";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
       return true;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was not entirely sure from your question if you are having issues with the service-side, client-side or both.  Our team found the following helpful when approaching WCF REST client/services for the first time.

For service-side guidance, the following Code Project article provides a comprehensive overview of hosting a WCF REST web service:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571813/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Creating-WCF-REST-Services

For client-side guidance, the following links provide good information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.method.aspx
http://forums.asp.net/t/1677895.aspx

Good luck.

Comment: I have actually followed the link : [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/255684/Create-and-Consume-RESTFul-Service-in-NET-Framewor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/255684/Create-and-Consume-RESTFul-Service-in-NET-Framewor).